# Font for U+A734, U+A735?

Tags: symbols, unicode, ligatures

I use Unicode Hex Input on macOS Catalina, and have the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}


testꜵ


\end{document}
```

However, my Texstudio does not show ꜵ, nor does the pdf it produces.

How may I produce the ꜵ with minimal additions?

Comment: Does the log file say anything about missing glyphs for the font?  Are you using pdflatex, xelatex, or lualatex?  I believe the last two are designed to handle UTF from the start, so that you don't even need the packages.

Comment: pdflatex just ives error messages.

Comment: @Teepeemm These google drive links are accessible:


Xetex-logfile:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dC5dLtBodtB2KjIK89wkmnzRsnIQhoKX/view?usp=sharing






Lualatexlogfile: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wnWvFBISvGk9RxfkEyRhbHS8ja2SHtQ7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Teepeemm pdflatex just gives error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use either `inputenc` or `fontenc` with xetex or luatex so start by removing them,
then use `fontspec` and specify any font that has these characters (eg you could use whichever font your browser picks to display the character).

I used the Windows Arial font here, as that has quite wide coverage.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}


testꜵ


\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks! Unfortunately it does not work for me.

Comment: The new `albatross` tool is useful here.

Comment: Here are a couple of screenshots from configurations:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wp3l6pewuc33ri6/Screen%20Shot%202020-12-31%20at%2017.25.46.png?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/st5w4zxnnkz4lad/Screen%20Shot%202020-12-31%20at%2017.28.11.png?dl=0

Comment: @Thérèse Where is the albatross?/ Sorry, I found it.

Comment: @Sapiens as I say you can see what font your browser use on this page to show your question (right menu "inspect" in firefox or chrome at least) and then use the same font.

Comment: I do not use terminal, so I may be handicapped ...

Comment: @Sapiens your editor configuration is not relevant at all, you can use xelatex or luatex with the default configuration, you just need to specify a font that has that character. I don't have a Mac but the font question is not really tex related at all, you could use Word or Libre Office or a web browser and have the same issue, you need a font that has the character.

Comment: How do I "inspect" the font used by my Chrome?

Comment: @Sapiens right menu `inspect` on the element with teh character in it then see what fonts are in use

Comment: @Dacid Carlisle it appeared as if it should be sans-serif, but that did not cut it. 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/utf2cygs81oczmq/Screen%20Shot%202020-12-31%20at%2017.50.37.png?dl=0

Comment: I succeeded in finding the font, viz. Arial. But unfortunately my Texstudio does not compile it. Next I will try with some other latex-editors.